# paypal recurring payments form

Tags: html, forms, wordpress, paypal

I have a website with a payment form,
I want to add recurring payments. 
how would i do that? what `ID`'s do I need to use in the form fields?

I saw a `WordPress` `plugin` that uses `a3` `t3` and `p3` like so:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="a3" value="" />
<p class="donate_recur"><label for="recur">Repeat Donation</label>
<select name="t3" id="t3">
                <option value="0"> Do not repeat </option> 
                 <option value="D"> Daily </option> 
                 <option value="W"> Weekly </option> 
                 <option value="M"> Monthly </option> 
                 <option value="Y"> Yearly </option> 
 </select> x 
<input name="p3" id="p3" value="'.$dplus['duration'].'" type="text" style="width:10px;" />
```

I'm not sure what `a3` is but `t3` is ever how long the transaction will happen, and `p3` is how many times it will happen.

I looked a little on the web and i found how to make a `PayPal` button for some kind of  product with recurring payments. but I need it to be dynamically inputted.

thank you.

Comment: refer https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
a3 - amount to billed each recurrence
p3 - number of time periods between each recurrence
t3 - time period (D=days, W=weeks, M=months, Y=years)


<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you. in the form i have the `cmd`s name is _donations and the form dosent have a name, it has an `ID` which is `donateplusform`. its a plugin. dose it matter? should i change them?

Comment: i tried to change the name and add the ID. the page i get seems wrong, it doesn't show the amount the user inserted.

Comment: The value for 'cmd' *must* be "_xclick-subscriptions". If it's "_donations", it means the plugin you're using is trying to set up (non-recurring) 'Donate' button.

Comment: And what do `sra` and `src` mean?

Comment: @FUT Here's what `sra` and `src` mean. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562581/what-do-the-src-and-sra-form-fields-for-paypal-ipn-html-form-do

Answer (score 4):

Mandatory fields are:

`a3`: Regular rate. This is the price of the subscription

`p3`: Regular billing cycle. This is the length of the billing cycle. The
number is modified by the regular billing cycle units (t3, below)

`t3`: Regular billing cycle units. This is the units of the
regular billing cycle (p3, above) Acceptable values are: D (days),
W (weeks), M (months), Y (years)

`no_note`: This field makes sure your subscriber is not prompted to include a
note with the subscription, a function which PayPal Subscriptions
does not support. This field must be included, and the value must
be set to 1.

Source:
[Subscriptions and recurring Payments Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/archive/PP_subscriptions.pdf)
from PayPal.

It's important to note that without the **optional** field `src` (also described in the doc above) the subscription expires just after the first transaction and threfore it's not recurrent:

`src`: Recurring payments. If set to “1,” the payment will recur unless
your customer cancels the subscription before the end of the
billing cycle. If omitted, the subscription payment will not recur
at the end of the billing cycle.