# What do the src and sra form fields for PayPal IPN HTML form do?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing

Example: [paypal recurring payments form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019954/paypal-recurring-payments-form)

When I have one enabled, it changes "for one month" to "for each month" on the checkout form, so why do I need two of them?

I've looked for the variables here and cannot find it. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB0901HT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see descriptions for those (and any other available parameter) in the [PayPal Standard Variables Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

[image]